# How to Use Time Interval In php To do same task

Tags: php

Hello guys i need the code with run php to a given time interval basically i am making recharge script and i need to put time gap

for example: i have done a recharge from script on any number  now i need to put 15 min time interval..if i will try to recharge before 15 min then script will show output...sorry you cant recharge before 15 min also need a timer which show how much time remaining to do another recharge on same number

...Help me guys please

Comment: What do you use as a data store? How does "recharging" work now?

Comment: log the time at first "recharge" then check that time when the user tries again.

Comment: i will use a file name'recharge.txt' to store data

Comment: i would use a db, not a flat file, but i have no idea what " recharge" is

Comment: Best way would be to store data in database and create a column to store last recharge time. When user fire another request then check if it is less than 15 minute. If yes you can discard the request.

Comment: If you still want to use file then also you will have to store last recharge time and then get this time when user fire another request. And do the same as mentioned in above comment

Comment: Just store the recharge time in the db. If the user tries again. check if time < 15 mins. If so, print the message. Otherwise, allow the recharge. Is this what you need?